# How to click a particular coordinate inside webbrowser control using c#

Tags: c#

I want to click a button which is at certain location (X,Y coordinate) inside a webbrowser control in windows form. But I am unable to find the correct location. The current coding shifts point somewhere else then the exact point.

```
private void Document_MouseUp(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            Point cp = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position); // Getting a cursor's position according form's area
            MessageBox.Show("Cursor position: X = " + cp.X + ", Y = " + cp.Y);

        }

webBrowser1.Document.MouseUp += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_MouseUp);

Point ScreenCoord = new Point(815, 192); //This value is returned by Document_MouseUp
            //Point BrowserCoord = webBrowser1.PointToClient(ScreenCoord);
            HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(ScreenCoord);
            if (elem.InnerText.Equals("Something"))
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
```

Comment: You shouldn't click/interact with or more technically "Automate" based on coordinates. What happens when the Screen size changes? Not related to your problem but you should invest time on WebApp test automation frameworks like Selenium.NET.

Comment: I did code using selenium but chromedriver.exe needs to be added in firewall, I don't want to do that. But as you said screen size matters, neither the screen size is  changing in my case nor the web page code. Can you kindly suggest a solution

Comment: Since details are missing. I am guessing you are using .NET Browser Control to render the HTML from some url/static page. Then you are trying to fire the button control which appears at X,Y coordinate. Remember those X,Y values were returned by the WinForms/WPF framework. Those are Relative to your Display/Monitor. That may not directly be the coordinate on the webpage. Since webpage have a Client Area/DOM Area which is the 0,0. Toolbar/Header etc are not counted in.

Comment: any solution to that?

Comment: this.PointToClient() is wrong, that gives the point relative to the form.  You meant this.webBrowser1.PointToClient()